# What is the relation between a nodeId and a key in distributed hash tables?

Tags: key-value, distributed-system, key-value-store, dht, kademlia

My understanding of a distributed hash table is that every node can be identified uniquely by a nodeId and can store information, like host, port and values. Every node stores other nodeIds in (a) lookup table(s) and finding another node can be made as efficient as *log(n)* with system size *n*. In order to retrieve the value from a node, one would need a key. Is the key for a value just the nodeId (i.e. a content identifier or hash of the value)? If so, then every node can only save one value? Or can a nodeId store multiple key-values, in which case the question arises how to retrieve a value without knowing which node contains which keys.

Comment: Nodes store data for keys near them, other nodes will send them a STOR message for values near their node ID.  The node ID itself is a random value.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there any ref that spcifies which nodes are eligible to store a value for a given key? Is an XOR distance of 4 okay? Maybe in a smaller networks the closest node has a distance of 80 bits. As it grows the value is still stored in this far away node. A lookup will not only take very long but might not converge, since a completely wrong corner of the network is explored.

Comment: Any node is eligible to store any key.  A node is meant to instruct the closest node that it finds when looking up a key that didn't know the key what the key/value is, so in a well behaving well functioning network, the closest node to a key will always know that key, along with at least one other backup node.  This is all laid out in the [Kademlia white paper](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~petar/papers/maymounkov-kademlia-lncs.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There are two general approaches for building distributed hash tables: distribute keys to nodes based on key values or based on hashes of keys. There are pros and cons for either option.

In either way, we will need to find a nodeId for a given key. A naive implementation could use modulus operation to find a target node. The problem with this approach is that when we do change number of nodes, then we have to remap absolutely every key - this is slow.

Let's say we have 4 nodes and the key is 10. 10 mod 4 is 2 an we will pick node #2 to store the data.

If you do need to handle node addition/removal efficiently, the common approach is called Consistent Hashing - that works similar to what you have described - we have multiple key (or hashes of key) intervals and assign many of those intervals to nodes - we require number of this intervals to be much larger than number of nodes. Hence if we add or remove a node, only some of those intervals need to be remapped to other nodes.